# using delayed_paperclip gem with delayed_job gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, delayed-job

i am working on a simple rails project and i use paperclip to upload attachments but when ever i use delayed job gem with delayed_paperclip gem i dont see the attachment. I followed the rdoc and tried it out but my guess is that i am not running delayed job well.

my attachment.rb lookes like this

```
has_attached_file :file
process_in_background :file
```

and i added this to my database

```
class AddFileProessingToAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :attachments, :file_processing, :boolean
  end
end
```

what else do i need to do again because i have waited for a long time and i still have a missing file.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that i have to start the delayed job task with the following command.

```
rake jobs:work
```

did not know until i checked my list of rake tasks